# Can eclipse RSE connect to a local port (ssh tunneled)?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, ssh-tunnel, eclipse-rse

I am using eclipse with RSE, and it works well connecting to my linux server when I am in the same network, but as the server is behind a firewall with a gate entry, I need to make a ssh tunnelling when outside its network.

I have not find a way of adding the local port where I have the tunnel to the host name nor in other places.

[image: RSE ssh connection]

Is it possible to connect to localhost:port with RSE?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Finally I found it.

You can not add a port in your initial connection configuration, so the way of doing it is to create a connection to localhost and give a proper name (in order to be able to map more ports later)

[image]

[image]

Then you will see your new resource

[image]

Your new connection is done in port 22 but you can change this and the name for the connection in the following steps.

For changing the user name, click in the resource ('remote_server_1' in this example) and in the `properties` (the bottom panel) you can change the `default userID`.

Now the next step is to change the port. For doing that you need to click either in the node `Sftp Files` or `Ssh Shells`

[image]

Go to the port and and change it to the local port where you have previously forwarded your ssh connection.

[image]

And that's it!, click now in the arrow in `My Home` or `Root` and you will be pronpted for your credentials:

[image]

**PD:**

Just in case you have the same problem for connecting remotely with eclipse, this is what I have installed, the dsdp/tm v 3.2

[image]

installing the RSE was a bit of trial and error because you need to unselect some packages not related with your architecture like winCE and others.

[image]

These are the packages that I installed in the plugin:

[image]

Comment: You are a stunning human being. May all your wishes come true!

Comment: BTW, the dialogs have changed a bit. I posted updated pics (V4.5.1) here:

http://superuser.com/questions/750814/eclipse-rse-setting-up-sftp-through-multiple-hops/1017681#1017681

Answer (score 0):

You can also right click on SFTP files -> Properties -> Subservice -> Port

[image]